# Apache Hive : Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to install Apache Hive, I insert HIVE_HOME and HADOOP_HOME into hive_config.sh and I copy some hive jar into the $HADOOP_HOME/lib
But when I try to launch it by using `hive` command this error appear :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
... 12 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
etc ...
```

ANY HELP PLEASE !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hadoop should be in running condition.
untar the downloaded hive and give the permission to the directory. Go to the hive/conf directory. Make hive-env.sh.template file to hive-env.sh and hive-default.xml.template file to hive-site.xml. Open hive-evn.sh and set JAVA_HOME in hive-env.sh and HADOOP_HOME and also set the hive path by.

```
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
```

then open hive terminal by

```
hive
```

by default hive takes Derby database, if it gives error of metastore at the time of create table, go to metastore/metastore_db and delete the *.lck files.

Add the JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, HIVE_HOME in .bashrc or .bash_profile.

```
$cd ~
$vi .bashrc

paste following to the end of the file



#Hadoop variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
###end of paste
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, my fault is that I missed to add the jars of hive to HADOOP_CLASSPATH : export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/elyes/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.0.6/lib/cassandra-driver-core-1.0.0-rc1-sources.jar:/home/elyes/hive/lib/*.jar

Answer (score 2):

hive --service metastore &

this command will start the metastore.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the above excpetion, starting hive metastore service worked for me

```
   $ hive --service metastore
```

cloudera reference doc on starting metastore service :

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_6.html

Answer (score 1):

no need to start metastore as service running hive cli will do same just make sure that you are executing hive command from same directory where you instantiate the hive metastore

Answer (score 0):

If you are a CDH user, you should build *Zeppelin* with correct parameters. These parameters will solve the problem for CDH 5.3.3:

```
mvn clean install -Pspark-1.4 -Phadoop-2.4 -DskipTests -Dspark.version=1.4.0 -Dhadoop.version=2.5.0-cdh5.3.3 -Dhive.hive.version=0.13.1-cdh5.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

From the property, it will create only the database but not the schema. Try creating the schema required for Hive metastore in MySQL

cd $HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/
 < login to mysql using command (mysql -u root -p) where root is the username and password will be asked>

```
mysql> use metastore;
 mysql> source hive-schema-<your_version>.mysql.sql;
```

e.g source hive-schema-2.1.0.mysql.sql;
Then restart hive metastore process using:

(hive --service metastore)
Hopefully, this will solve the problem!